# Cant access Spring Security UI?

Tags: grails, user-interface, spring-security, http-status-code-404

I am currently trying to access the GUI for Spring Security UI. I have all the necessary plugins installed as shown below:

```
cache               1.1.1            --  Cache Plugin
cloud-foundry       1.2.3            --  Cloud Foundry Integration
cloud-support       1.0.11           --  Cloud Support Plugin
codenarc            0.20             --  CodeNarc plugin
constraints         0.6.0            --  Custom domain constraints plugin
csv                 0.3.1            --  Grails CSV Plugin
database-migration  1.1              --  Grails Database Migration Plugin
dynamic-config      0.3              --  Dynamic-Config-Plugin
export              1.5              --  Export Plugin
famfamfam           1.0.1            --  Silk icons from famfamfam.com
hibernate           2.1.0            --  Hibernate for Grails
jquery              1.10.2           --  JQuery for Grails
jquery-ui           1.10.3           --  jQuery UI Plugin
jquery-validation   1.9              --  JQuery Validation Plugin
jquery-validation-ui1.4.4            --  JQuery Validation UI Plugin - Client Side Validation without writing JavaScript
kickstart-with-bootstrap0.6.1b           --  Kickstart with Bootstrap - Good looking websites!
mail                1.0.1            --  Provides Mail support to a running Grails application
mandrill            0.1              --  Grails Mandrill Plugin
navigation          1.3.2            --  Site Menu Navigation
resources           1.2.7            --  Resources
rest                0.7              --  REST client facilities
settings            1.4              --  Application settings (global constants) plugin
spock               0.7              --  Spock Plugin - spockframework.org
spring-security-core2.0-RC2          --  Spring Security Core Plugin
spring-security-oauth2-provider1.0.5.2          --  OAuth2 Provider support for the Spring Security plugin.
spring-security-ui  1.0-RC1          --  Spring Security UI
tomcat              2.1.0            --  Apache Tomcat plugin for Grails
webxml              1.4.1            --  WebXmlConfig
wslite              0.7.1.0          --  Wslite plugin
```

Whenever I try to access any of the following URL's I get 404 not found errors:

```
/user/create
/user
/role/search
etc...
```

Can someone please help me resolve this issue as I am not receiving any errors and looks to be installed, just cant access it :)

Thanks in advance

---

*****EDIT*****************

---

I have also tried to override the domain, so the following command did work which would suggest to me the plugin is installed:

```
grails s2ui-override user com.mypackage
```

But when running the application I get this error:

```
UserController.groovy: 3: unable to resolve class grails.plugin.springsecurity.ui.UserController
```

Can someone please help me with this as its very confusing and need to recify this issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can someone please help? :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to track down the issue and wanted to share encase anyone else encounters this.

The issue was that I had an old install of Spring Security UI that I used in this project as a local plugin by doing the following in the build config:

```
grails.plugin.location.'spring-security-ui'='plugins/s2ui'

inherits("global"){
   excludes 'spring-security-ui'
}
```

So the line above that excludes the "spring-security-ui" from being a dependency was the issue, once I removed that, uninstalled and re-installed the plugin it was all good.

Thanks